# How to fetch a list of current SSL connections in Windows?

Tags: windows, ssl

We have computer and an application written in Java. The application must work with SSL only.

Is there any way to fetch a list of current SSL connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the port on which the Java App listens, you should be able to view connections with the netstat command.
If your machine is behind a firewall, you (or your network admin) should be able to monitor traffic to the machine - which might be easier and cleaner than using a sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Windows only tracks TCP connections and does not know anything about SSL/TLS, which works at a higher level than TCP.

What you *can* do is use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor all network traffic, or [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which TCP/UDP ports your program is connecting to. (Port monitoring is not very fool-proof, though.)

Comment: How about netstat?

Comment: If you can find the word "SSL" in netstat's output, sure. Like I said the OS only tracks low level TCP connections.